# Can't install Visual Studio 2010 sp1 on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2010

I've got VS2010 installed and when I try to install sp1, downloaded from Microsoft, I get this error message:

> A compatible version of Visual Studio 2010 was not detected on the system. This update is designed for only the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

VS2010 is for sure installed, so what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turned out that vs2010 was **not** properly installed on the machine.  The installer completed, but there were errors, and I'm guessing that some of these errors are related my my problem.  Unfortunately, I can't get vs2010 installed properly at all, and so I'm giving up and switching to vs2012.  I hope I never need to return to 2010, because it simply won't install on Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

> This error may occur if you have ASP.NET MVC 3 RC or Visual Studio Async CTP installed in
> your system already.
>
> Also refer below link for more details about this,
> [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jasonz/announcing-visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1-beta?PageIndex=3)

**Source:**

http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/290925-What-requirements-VS-2010-installation.aspx

Try if you also have those pre-Release Tools installed.

Comment: I don't think that could be the problem, because it's a brand new Windows 8 machine, fresh out of the box.